# SQLGroup with Distinct count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query

```
select count(distinct(a.studentid)count,
    case
      when a.Age <=19 then '1-19'
      when a.Age between 20 and 29 then '20-29'
    end as age_range
from table a 
where 0 = 0
group by a.age
```

Outcome

```
count  age_range
 10      1-19
  5      1-19
 12      20-29
 18      20-29
```

Not sure why not group by range and expect results. Thank you.

```
 count   age_range
 15       1-19
 30       20-29
```

Comment: The reason for the unexpected outcome is that the `case` expression was applied *after* grouping. Apparently you have four different ages in that data thus four output rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest `cross apply` to define the alias:

```
select v.age_range, count(distinct a.studentid)count,
from table a cross apply
     (values (case when a.Age <= 19 then 'Under 12 months-19'
                   when a.Age between 20 and 29 then '20-29'
              end)
     ) as v(age_range)
group by v.age_range;
```

SQL Server doesn't allow aliases as `GROUP BY` keys.  I think defining the alias in the `FROM` clause is the simplest method; you could also use a CTE or subquery or repeat the `case` expression.

I should also note that the `between` is not needed for the `case`.  The clauses are evaluated in order so you could use:

```
(case when a.Age <= 19 then 'Under 12 months-19'
      when a.Age <= 29 then '20-29'
 end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by your case statement:

```
select count(distinct(a.studentid)count,
    case
      when a.Age <=19 then 'Under 12 months-19'
      when a.Age between 20 and 29 then '20-29'
    end as age_range
from table a 
where 0 = 0
group by case
      when a.Age <=19 then 'Under 12 months-19'
      when a.Age between 20 and 29 then '20-29'
    end
```

OR simply:

```
select count(distinct(a.studentid)count,
    case
      when a.Age <=19 then 'Under 12 months-19'
      when a.Age between 20 and 29 then '20-29'
    end as age_range
from table a 
where 0 = 0
group by 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to keep TIERS in a generalized Tier table thus removing logic from code and allowing you to server multiple masters.

**Example**

```
Declare @Tier table (Tier_Grp varchar(50),Tier_R1 money,Tier_R2 money,Tier_Title varchar(50))
Insert Into @Tier values
 ('Age Range',1 , 20,' 1-19')
,('Age Range',21, 29,'21-29')
,('Age Range',31, 39,'31-39')
,('Age Range',40,999,'Over 40')
,('Age Range',1 ,999,'Total')


Select A.Tier_R1
      ,A.Tier_R2
      ,A.Tier_Title
      ,Cnt   =  count(Distinct studentid)
 From @Tier A
 Left Join  YourTable B 
        on A.Tier_Grp='Age Range'
           and B.Age>=A.Tier_R1 
           and B.Age<A.Tier_R2
 Group By A.Tier_R1
         ,A.Tier_R2
         ,A.Tier_R2
 Order By Tier_R1,Tier_R2
```